# string-to-json module not working correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have string data

```
var str2json = require('string-to-json');        
var data={
            "GTIN" : "GTIN 3",
            "Target Market" : "Target Market 3",
            "Global Location Provider Name(GLN) 3" : "Global Location Provider Name(GLN) 3",
            "Information Provider Name 3" : "Information Provider Name 3",
            "Product Overview" : "Product Overview 3",  
         }
```

I am using str2json module I am converting this to JSON object, 
when I am using      `var output = str2json.convert(data);` It is not working for me but when I am using

```
var output = str2json.convert({
            "GTIN" : "GTIN 3",
            "Target Market" : "Target Market 3",
            "Global Location Provider Name(GLN) 3" : "Global Location Provider Name(GLN) 3",
            "Information Provider Name 3" : "Information Provider Name 3",
            "Product Overview" : "Product Overview 3",  
         })
```

it is working fine and giving the out put like this

```
{ GTIN: 'GTIN 3',
  'Target Market': 'Target Market 3',
  'Global Location Provider Name(GLN) 3': 'Global Location Provider Name(GLN) 3',
  'Information Provider Name 3': 'Information Provider Name 3',
  'Product Overview': 'Product Overview 3' }
```

Then what is error with `var output = str2json.convert(data);`

Comment: `data` doesn't look like string. It seems like a valid data object.

Comment: `It is not working for me` What does this mean? Are there errors? If so, what errors?

Comment: After reading the Documentation https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-to-json, I don't think you need the `string-to-json` library at all. You don't have any dots in your keys.

Answer (score 0):

For string to json conversion, you can use builtin JSON.parse() Reference: [JSON -Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

More over the **data** object in your code is a valid JSON object (if the **trailing comma** is removed).

`{
    "GTIN": "GTIN 3",
    "Target Market": "Target Market 3",
    "Global Location Provider Name(GLN) 3": "Global Location Provider Name(GLN) 3",
    "Information Provider Name 3": "Information Provider Name 3",
    "Product Overview": "Product Overview 3"
}`